# How to get the globals from a module namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, namespaces, global

Is there a way to get the *dictionary* containing the global variables in a specific module namespace? It looks that you can achieve it if the module contains at least one function with something like:

```
import mymodule
d = mymodule.func.__globals__
```

Is this right?

Is there a more general way? (For instance, how could this be done if the module wouldn't contain any function but only variables?)

I am not expecting a *"What are you trying to do with that? There is probably another way of doing it."* answer; my question is rather a theoretical one.

I am more interested here by a Python3 answer if it matters.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just grab use `vars` which grabs its `__dict__` which corresponds to the global scope.

```
vars(mymodule)
```

`func.__globals__` simply returns this dictionary for you see how:

```
vars(mymodule) is mymodule.func.__globals__
```

returns `True`.

Comment: Or just use its `__dict__` directly. I've always preferred `__dict__`. One less level of parentheses to nest.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @user2357112 Yup, I personally shy away from grabbing dunders and instead opt for the function version that does it for me (even though `__dict__` is probably never changing so I'm being paranoid.)