# how to get a variable data when class is first defined in python?

Tags: python, oop, variables, scope, global-variables

I have 2 python scripts in which I'm trying to access a variable from one of the python scripts and use it in another python script during the class definition or initialization.

For example , here are the 2 scripts

```
script1.py 

dname = None
class Invenger(BBCAPIInfra):
    def __init__(self,
                 server_ip):
    def get_dname_from_bed(self, dip):
          global dname
          dname = dip.foo.bar
          return dname
```

This is the second script where I want to use the value of dname

```
script2.py 


from foo.bar.abc.script1 import dname

class LAUtils(BBCAPIInfra):
    yml_path = dname
```

I have 1 more script which is actually I'm triggering from command line and it  looks like this

```
#script3.py 

from script1 import Invenger

class CommonSetup(commonsetup):
    def common_setup:    
    test.params['inv'] = Invenger(server_ip=self.server_ip)

    def get_dname:
      inv.get_dname_from_bed(dip)
      print(dname)
```

Here when I execute the scripts, I get `yml_path =None` which is correct, but how can I change the script to get the actual value of `dname` in script2  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the globals from a module namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387963/how-to-get-the-globals-from-a-module-namespace)

Answer (score 1):

To share the value of `dname` between `script1.py` and `script2.py`, you can create a separate module to store the shared variable and then import it in both scripts. Here's how you can modify your scripts:

1. Create a new module called `shared.py` to store the shared variable `dname`:

```py
# shared.py
dname = None
```

2. Modify `script1.py` to use the `shared.py` module:

```py
# script1.py
from shared import dname

class Invenger(BBCAPIInfra):
    def __init__(self, server_ip):
        ...

    def get_dname_from_bed(self, dip):
        global dname
        dname = dip.foo.bar
        return dname
```

3. Modify `script2.py` to use the `shared.py` module:

```py
# script2.py
from shared import dname

class LAUtils(BBCAPIInfra):
    yml_path = dname
```

4. Modify `script3.py` to pass the `dip` value to `Invenger` and then access the updated `dname` value from `shared.py`:

```py
# script3.py
from script1 import Invenger
from shared import dname

class CommonSetup(commonsetup):
    def common_setup(self):    
        inv = Invenger(server_ip=self.server_ip)
        dip = ...  # Define the value of dip here
        inv.get_dname_from_bed(dip)
        print(dname)
```

Now, when you run `script3.py`, it should correctly update the `dname` variable in `shared.py` through `script1.py` and use the updated value in `script2.py`. Make sure to define the appropriate value for `dip` in `script3.py` to correctly update `dname`.

Comment: This can't possibly work. The line `dname = dip.foo.bar` only affects the global within that module.